# Python Function Inputs with Varying Data Types

Tags: function, python-3.x

I'm brand new to Python and come from a C/C++ background. I'm looking for a way to differentiate function calls based on the data that is being passed.

An example:

```
class RomanNumeral():
    def __init__( self, value ):
        # Assign stuff
```

Now, let's say I'd like to be able to initialize an instance of RomanNumeral with either an int or a string (e.g., 11 or XI). How is this handled in Python?

I'm essentially looking for this C++ equivalent:

```
RomanNumeral();
RomanNumeral(int value);
RomanNumeral(string value);
```

Do I have to throw a `try` block around some code and catch ValueError if I'm given a string?

Answer (score 0):

Python does not complain about type mismatch like C++. Syntactically, you can assign any data type to any variable. For your case,

```
class RomanNumeral:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
```

And in any method you use it, you can:

```
    def some_method(self):
        if isinstance(self.value, int):
            print "Value is a number"
        elif isinstance(self.value, str):
            print "Value is a Roman Number"
```

This is a simple way to handle types in Python